# XMLHttpRequest cannot load and Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400 for put method

Tags: angularjs

[I am not getting exact solution of XMLHttpRequest cannot load and Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400 error while updating the form , i use this code

updateUser: function (user, $scope, $httpParamSerializer) {

```
                var userdata = {
                    AddCustomerId: user.AddCustomerId,
                    SapCode: user.SapCode,
                    CustomerCode: user.CustomerCode,
                    CompanyName: user.CompanyName,
                    Address: user.Address,
                    ContactPerson: user.ContactPerson,
                    ContactNumber: user.ContactNumber,
                    PinCode: user.PinCode,
                    CreationDate: user.CreationDate,
                    CustomerTypeCustomerTypeId: $scope.CustomerTypeId,
                    CountryCountryID: $scope.CountryID
                };


                var RequestHeader = {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
                    },
                    url: baseAddress + '/api/AddCustomers/' + user.AddCustomerId,
                    data: $httpParamSerializer(userdata)

            }

             return  $http(RequestHeader);
            }
```

this code is working for get and post event but for put and delete method its not working , please provide me any best solution

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vp2fL.png)

Comment: Show response headers (copy from browser dev tools network). It sounds like CORS not set up to allow those methods

Comment: 400 BadRequest... i assume the server is not accepting PUT requests!